# What can cause python registered signals to be ignored?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, signals, mutex

I have a python script with multiple `threading`-launched threads in which several threads occasionally freeze (apparently simultaneously). In this script, I've registered a signal handler to dump stack traces from all the running threads. When it's frozen, no dumped stacks appear. What could be causing this?

A couple of possibilities that come to mind:

- A thread is not releasing a `mutex`, freezing any other threads that attempt to acquire it. I would expect the signal handler to work in this case, however. Am I mistaken?
- I log various things to `stdout` and `stderrr`, which are redirected with a bash command line to a log file. Perhaps precisely timed output from 2 threads could be blocking at OS level? This script has been running for months without problems, though there was a kernel update just recently (it's Ubuntu 12.04). If this is the case, the signal is not being ignored, just not producing any output...
- I have a few global variables that are read and written by the freezing threads. I had thought that python 2.7 has a global thread lock to make this safe, and it's not been a problem before.

Answer (score 3):

Python's `signal` module runs signal handlers on the main interpreter thread exclusively. If your main thread is hung and unable to execute Python code, your signal handlers will not run. Signals will be fired and caught, but if the thread can't execute Python code then nothing will happen.

The best way to avoid this situation is to ensure your main thread (the first thread that exists in the Python interpreter upon startup) does not deadlock. This may mean ensuring that nothing important happens on that thread after initialization.

Comment: Shouldn't the very nature of signals let them run anyways?

Comment: @zneak: Python can't run Python code in a signal handler as it would be very unsafe. So, Python defers signal work until the main thread is available to run it. The main thread will run pending calls when it attempts to fetch a bytecode instruction.

Comment: @nneonneo: That's interesting that Python tries to defer the signal handler to a safe time. Because Python actually [fails](https://bugs.python.org/issue24283) to achieve that goal, and one invariably ends up writing Python code to defer the handler again, to an actual safe time.